# sshd: "no hostkey alg" fixed but still confused

Tags: configuration, sshd

Apparently Fedora 35 does not list ssh-rsa in HostKeyAlgorithms or PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes so trying to ssh from an old CentOS 6 machine yielded an error:

```
$ ssh as1s16.intra.corp.us
no hostkey alg
```

So I added options after the Include in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

but same error. Then I ran sshd like this:

```
# /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
...
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:20 setting HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:21 setting PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
...
debug1: SELinux support disabled [preauth]
...
debug3: append_hostkey_type: ssh-rsa key not permitted by HostkeyAlgorithms [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
```

but same error. Then I removed the options ran sshd like this:

```
# /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -oHostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa
```

and it worked. I was able to successfully ssh in from the CentOS 6 client.

So then I put the options BEFORE the Include:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa

# To modify the system-wide sshd configuration, create a  *.conf  file under
#  /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/  which will be automatically included below
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
```

and it worked.

Why would I need to put these directives BEFORE the Include? Shouldn't they go after to override the defaults?

Comment: "Shouldn't they go after to override the defaults?" No, `sshd_config` is first-directive-wins.  They will have to go **before** to override the defaults.  [See man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)): "For each keyword, the first obtained value will be used."

Comment: Even if I had read that, I would not have understood it because it doesn't make sense. There should be an indented note in the man page about that. It would make more sense to derive new configurations by including different files. That is how code works and configuration directives essentially code. As it is, the "code" is one big set of static finals.

Answer (score 0):

Although that wording isn't very clear, I suspect that the `config.d/*` directory is to allow separate config files for particular clients/users or incoming interface/port(s), as opposed to 'system-wide'. This would be similar to the use of `sites/*` directories in apache/httpd and nginx (and probably more) to allow each virtual host or application to be configured separately but still all be supported by one server. **Look in those files** to see if they contain Match lines (which should be followed by other real lines = not Match, comment, or blank) which means they apply to only certain connections and not all.

[Include](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Include) is textual. If you have a file

```
blich
Include file*
blech
```

where blich and blech don't contain [Match](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) lines but at least some file(s) do(es), then effectively blech becomes part of the last Match block from the concatenation of the files -- so the settings in blech are only used for incoming connections satisfying those Match condition(s), which your test connection apparently didn't.

If you want SSHD settings to be 'global' you must put them before any Match line(s), and if the Include'd file(s) contain(s) Match line(s) that means you must put the global settings before the Include.

All (used) settings in the config file override defaults in the program. Putting the same setting more than once in the config file (before/outside any Match blocks) uses the *first* one not the last, so your idea of overriding an earlier 'default' (which isn't a default at all if it's in the file) wouldn't work. Only when the later occurrence is in a Match block whose condition(s) is(are) satisfied does it override the first one.

PS: this presumably happened now because Fedora is bleeding-edge and [OpenSSH recently changed this finally](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8) after warning (threatening?) they would do so since 8.2 a year and a half ago.

Comment: Regardless of whether the included files contain `Match` lines, any **global** declaration of either `Key` directive will override anything that comes later.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restarted sshd.